# In Dart/Flutter, how do I use a variable from a method so I can ouput it to a text field

Tags: flutter, methods, dart

Hope somebody can help - I hit this dead end a few weeks ago and think that I've tried everything within my limited knowledge.

I've set up a database that works OK - that is I can add data on one screen, review the data and edit the data on another screen.  Now I want to sum one of the columns (beef) which I've been able to do as proven in the 'debugPrint' to the console.  I want to access this variable 'beefTotal' from the 'sumBeef' method and print show this in a text field in the UI.  I just can't manage it though.  It just returns null.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:take_note/utils/database_helper.dart';

class Info extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _InfoState();
}

DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper();
var database = DatabaseHelper();

class _InfoState extends State<Info> {
  List beefTotal;

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Beef Info"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      sumBeef();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Total Beef is: £ $beefTotal", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                  ),),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  void sumBeef () async {
    beefTotal = await database.addBeef();
    debugPrint("Total beef: $beefTotal");
  }
}
```

The code below is from a class called DatabaseHelper which the method sumBeef() uses

````
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> addBeef()async{
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(beef) FROM $table");

    return result;
  }
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L46Gj.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call 
setState({

});

```
void sumBeef () async {
 beefTotal = await database.addBeef();
 setState(() {});
 debugPrint("Total beef: $beefTotal");
}
```

and your good! anytime you make a change you have to call setState method to update the ui (rebuild) in flutters case

Comment: You're a genius!  Thanks a lot.  One final question if it's not too much trouble - the output is now 'Total Beef is: £[{SUM(beef):205.0}].  How do I just get the £205.0?

Comment: There is issue with your SQL query you wanna do db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(beef) as cash FROM $table"); then you need to get the var cash from your result :)

Comment: Assign result to new var beefRow = await database.addBeef(); then use beefTotal = beefRow["cash"].toString();

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand your answer - I did the following:

Comment: void sumBeef () async {

    beefTotal = await database.addBeef();
    var beefRow = await database.addBeef();
    beefTotal = beefRow["cash"].toString();
    setState(() {
    });
    debugPrint("Total beef: $beefTotal");
  }

Comment: Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> addBeef()async{
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(beef) as cash FROM $table");

    return result;
  }

Comment: the IDE reports that 'a value of type String cannot be assigned to a variable of type list'

Comment: Change the var to string as you have it as List